# Orange3 install through Anaconda Prompt gets stuck on 'solving environment'

Tags: anaconda, orange

opened anaconda prompt as administrator,
first updated conda using

```
conda update conda
```

then tried installing Orange3 using

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install pyqt
conda install orange3
```

as per https://orangedatamining.com/download/#windows.

gave me the following problem:
[image: Anaconda prompt]

it stays on this for at least an hour.

What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: Same issue here. Can you share the System Details, OS?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command and worked in OS WIN11.

```
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/gcc7" orange3
```